# Improving Performance on 2 Left Joins and multiple SUMs in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance, indexing

I'm no MySQL expert as it probably shows from my query below, but I've managed to get my query to give me the results i want, but it seems very slow to me:

```
SELECT 
    bouts.bout_id,
    bouts.bout_date,
    bouts.winner,
    bouts.result,
    bouts.ended_in_round,
    bouts.total_rounds,
    bouts.verified AS verified,
    CONCAT(opponent.first_name, ' ', opponent.last_name) AS opponent_name,
    opponent.last_name AS opponent_lastname,
    opponent.id AS opponent_id,
    IF(opponent.id = bouts.boxer_1, bouts.boxer_1_weight, bouts.boxer_2_weight) AS opp_weight,
    IF(opponent.id = bouts.boxer_1, bouts.boxer_2_weight, bouts.boxer_1_weight) AS fighter_weight,
    SUM(opp_bouts.ended_in_round) AS opp_total_rounds_boxed,
    SUM(IF(opp_bouts.winner = -1,1,0)) AS opp_draws,
    SUM(IF(opp_bouts.winner = opponent.id,1,0)) AS opp_wins,
    COUNT(opp_bouts.bout_id) AS opp_fights,
    IF(opponent.id = bouts.boxer_1, bouts.bxr2_power_points, bouts.bxr1_power_points) AS boxer_power,
    IF(opponent.id = bouts.boxer_1, bouts.bxr2_chin_points, bouts.bxr1_chin_points) AS boxer_chin,
    IF(opponent.id = bouts.boxer_1, bouts.bxr2_boxer_points, bouts.bxr1_boxer_points) AS boxer_boxer,
    SUM(IF(opponent.id = opp_bouts.boxer_1, opp_bouts.bxr1_power_points, opp_bouts.bxr2_power_points)) AS opp_power,
    SUM(IF(opponent.id = opp_bouts.boxer_1, opp_bouts.bxr1_chin_points, opp_bouts.bxr2_chin_points)) AS opp_chin,
    SUM(IF(opponent.id = opp_bouts.boxer_1, opp_bouts.bxr1_boxer_points, opp_bouts.bxr2_boxer_points)) AS opp_boxer,
    SUM(IF(opponent.id = opp_bouts.boxer_1, opp_bouts.bxr1_exp_points, opp_bouts.bxr2_exp_points)) AS opp_experience,
    MAX(IF(opp_bouts.verified = 1, opp_bouts.bout_date, 0)) AS verified_up_to,
    MAX(opp_bouts.bout_date) AS opp_last_bout
FROM
    bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id=IF(bouts.boxer_2 = '" . $boxer_id . "', bouts.boxer_1, bouts.boxer_2)
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON (opp_bouts.boxer_1=opponent.id OR opp_bouts.boxer_2=opponent.id) AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
WHERE bouts.bout_date < '" . $to_date . "' AND (bouts.boxer_1 = '" . $boxer_id . "' OR bouts.boxer_2 = '" . $boxer_id . "')
GROUP BY bouts.bout_id
ORDER BY bouts.bout_date DESC
```

`bouts` has around 11,570 rows, `boxers` has around 86,370 rows, and it's currently taking between 0.6500 - 0.7500 seconds to run. I have a primary key on `boxers.id` and `bouts.bout_id`, and indexes on `bouts.boxer_1` and `bouts.boxer_2`, but my knowledge of using indexes isn't too good either.

Is it normal for the query to be this slow, and is there anything i can do to help speed it up a little?

**UPDATE**

Explain result of the query. You'll have to let me know if this isn't correct...

[image: MySQL explain output]

**UPDATE 2**

Bout table structure:

[image]

Boxer table structure:

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

Ok, some progress maybe...

If i change

`LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON (opp_bouts.boxer_1=opponent.id OR opp_bouts.boxer_2=opponent.id) AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date`

to:

`LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON (opp_bouts.boxer_1=opponent.id) AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date`

It speeds the query up to around 0.0250, and this seems to be a big speed issue. Could i improve the OR function or do it in a different way maybe?

**UPDATE 4**

Thanks to Kickstart i now have the below code which is soo much faster but I'm not 100% I've done everything correctly... or if i should have indexes on some columns to speed it up further? I'm not sure how it'll scale up yet wither, but it might be the best I'll get?

`bouts` now has ~46,066 rows and `boxers` ~90,531, the query runs at 0.0466 with index on bout_date and both boxer_1/2.

```
SELECT bout_id, 
        bout_date,
        winner,
        result,
        ended_in_round,
        total_rounds,
        verified,
        opponent_first_name,
        opponent_last_name,
        opponent_id,
        opp_weight,
        fighter_weight,
        SUM(opp_ended_in_round) AS opp_total_rounds_boxed,
        SUM(IF(opp_winner = -1,1,0)) AS opp_draws,
        SUM(IF(opp_winner = opponent_id,1,0)) AS opp_wins,
        COUNT(opp_id) AS opp_fights,
        boxer_power,
        boxer_chin,
        boxer_boxer,
        SUM(opp_power_rating) AS opp_power,
        SUM(opp_chin_rating) AS opp_chin,
        SUM(opp_boxer_rating) AS opp_boxer,
        SUM(opp_exp_rating) AS opp_experience,
        MIN(IF(opp_verified = 1,9999-01-01 , opp_bout_date)) AS verified_up_to,
        MAX(opp_bout_date) AS opp_last_bout
    FROM (

    SELECT bouts.bout_id, bouts.total_rounds, bouts.result, bouts.verified, opp_bouts.verified AS opp_verified, opp_bouts.bout_id AS opp_id, bouts.winner, opp_bouts.winner AS opp_winner, bouts.ended_in_round, opp_bouts.ended_in_round AS opp_ended_in_round, bouts.boxer_2_weight AS opp_weight, bouts.bxr1_power_points AS boxer_power, opp_bouts.bxr1_power_points AS opp_power_rating , opp_bouts.bxr1_chin_points AS opp_chin_rating, opp_bouts.bxr1_boxer_points AS opp_boxer_rating, opp_bouts.bxr1_exp_points AS opp_exp_rating, bouts.bxr1_chin_points AS boxer_chin, bouts.bxr1_boxer_points AS boxer_boxer, bouts.boxer_1_weight AS fighter_weight, bouts.boxer_2 AS opponent_id, bouts.bout_date, opp_bouts.bout_date AS opp_bout_date, opponent.first_name AS opponent_first_name, opponent.last_name AS opponent_last_name
    FROM bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id = boxer_2
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON opp_bouts.boxer_1 = opponent.id AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
    WHERE bouts.bout_date < 'NOW()'
    AND bouts.boxer_1 = '63514'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT bouts.bout_id, bouts.total_rounds, bouts.result, bouts.verified, opp_bouts.verified AS opp_verified, opp_bouts.bout_id AS opp_id, bouts.winner, opp_bouts.winner AS opp_winner, bouts.ended_in_round, opp_bouts.ended_in_round AS opp_ended_in_round, bouts.boxer_2_weight AS opp_weight, bouts.bxr1_power_points AS boxer_power, opp_bouts.bxr2_power_points AS opp_power_rating, opp_bouts.bxr2_chin_points AS opp_chin_rating, opp_bouts.bxr2_boxer_points AS opp_boxer_rating, opp_bouts.bxr2_exp_points AS opp_exp_rating, bouts.bxr1_chin_points AS boxer_chin, bouts.bxr1_boxer_points AS boxer_boxer, bouts.boxer_1_weight AS fighter_weight, bouts.boxer_2 AS opponent_id, bouts.bout_date, opp_bouts.bout_date AS opp_bout_date, opponent.first_name AS opponent_first_name, opponent.last_name AS opponent_last_name
    FROM bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id = boxer_2
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON opp_bouts.boxer_2 = opponent.id AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
    WHERE bouts.bout_date < 'NOW()'
    AND bouts.boxer_1 = '63514'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT bouts.bout_id, bouts.total_rounds, bouts.result, bouts.verified, opp_bouts.verified AS opp_verified, opp_bouts.bout_id AS opp_id, bouts.winner, opp_bouts.winner AS opp_winner, bouts.ended_in_round, opp_bouts.ended_in_round AS opp_ended_in_round, bouts.boxer_1_weight AS opp_weight, bouts.bxr2_power_points AS boxer_power, opp_bouts.bxr1_power_points AS opp_power_rating, opp_bouts.bxr1_chin_points AS opp_chin_rating, opp_bouts.bxr1_boxer_points AS opp_boxer_rating, opp_bouts.bxr1_exp_points AS opp_exp_rating, bouts.bxr2_chin_points AS boxer_chin, bouts.bxr2_boxer_points AS boxer_boxer, bouts.boxer_2_weight AS fighter_weight, bouts.boxer_1 AS opponent_id, bouts.bout_date, opp_bouts.bout_date AS opp_bout_date, opponent.first_name AS opponent_first_name, opponent.last_name AS opponent_last_name
    FROM bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id = boxer_1
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON opp_bouts.boxer_1 = opponent.id AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
    WHERE bouts.bout_date < 'NOW()'
    AND bouts.boxer_2 = '63514'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT bouts.bout_id, bouts.total_rounds, bouts.result, bouts.verified, opp_bouts.verified AS opp_verified, opp_bouts.bout_id AS opp_id, bouts.winner, opp_bouts.winner AS opp_winner, bouts.ended_in_round, opp_bouts.ended_in_round AS opp_ended_in_round, bouts.boxer_1_weight AS opp_weight, bouts.bxr2_power_points AS boxer_power, opp_bouts.bxr2_power_points AS opp_power_rating, opp_bouts.bxr2_chin_points AS opp_chin_rating, opp_bouts.bxr2_boxer_points AS opp_boxer_rating, opp_bouts.bxr2_exp_points AS opp_exp_rating, bouts.bxr2_chin_points AS boxer_chin, bouts.bxr2_boxer_points AS boxer_boxer, bouts.boxer_2_weight AS fighter_weight, bouts.boxer_1 AS opponent_id, bouts.bout_date, opp_bouts.bout_date AS opp_bout_date, opponent.first_name AS opponent_first_name, opponent.last_name AS opponent_last_name
    FROM bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id = boxer_1
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON opp_bouts.boxer_2 = opponent.id AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
    WHERE bouts.bout_date < 'NOW()'
    AND bouts.boxer_2 = '63514'
) AS my_table GROUP BY bout_id ORDER BY bout_date DESC
```

Comment: Can you do an EXPLAIN on that query and post the results?

Comment: Have you tried using `explain` to examine the query? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the following fields: `boxers.id`, `bouts.boxer_1`, `bouts.boxer_2`, `bouts.bout_date`, `bouts.winner`, `bouts.boxer_1_weight`, `bouts.boxer_2_weight`, `bouts.ended_in_round`, `bouts.bout_id` Also, add the keyword 'EXPLAIN' before the keyword 'SELECT' and run that. It would be helpful to edit your question with the results of the explain as well

Comment: after a short look at your query: you should put an index on opp_bouts.bout_date and think about using join instead of left join. Joins are much faster but sometimes you need left joins. it depends on your usage.

Comment: Since you are using string comparison in your ON condition, maybe the optimizer can not use indexes for your joins. It might be an idea to join both boxers (not only the right type) as two joins and determine the one to use in your WHERE clause (or maybe even in your PHP). That way, you have a chance to use indexes in your ON conditions, however at the price od doing one more JOIN.

Comment: Updated my post to include the explain result. I'll get trying some of the requested ideas so far... :)

Comment: @PhilCross I've tried the suggested indexes but it doesn't seem to have had any effect

Comment: Since you still don't have any definitive answers.  Can you edit your post and list the structures of the tables too - to help me wrap my head around a few things.

Comment: @DRapp Thanks for your help, I've updated my question with the structures.

Comment: @DRapp Any suggestions? It would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @john, we might need to go into a chat on this... I'll probably have more comments/question than drag this post along for the ride.  If you open a chat, let me know and we can try to get going.

Comment: @DRapp I can't figure out how the chat works, but i may have found where the loss of speed is coming from anyway... I've updated my question :)

Comment: To go with your last update, you can replace the OR with unioned queries. This is in line with my suggestion.

Comment: You possibly want an extra couple of indexes covering 2 columns on the bouts table. On both the boxer_1 / bout_date combination and the boxer_2 / bout_date combination. However I suspect that given your data the current indexes will be pretty efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using IF to decide on just about all the columns whether you are referring to the first or 2nd boxer will likely slow things down.

Possibly best to have 2 subselects (one for each of boxer_1 and boxer_2), union the results together and then to the SUMs and COUNTs on the results of that.

EDIT. Brief example (not full as I don't fully understand where all the data is coming from). Have 4 queries unioned together (1 for each of boxer_1 and boxer_2 on bouts, and again one of each for those on the 2nd join on bouts). Use the results of this unioned query to do you actual calculations.

```
SELECT SomeFields,
SUM(SomeField),
etc
FROM
(
    SELECT bouts.boxer_1 AS boxer, bouts.boxer_2 AS opponent, opp_bouts.boxer_2 AS opponentsPrevOpponent
    FROM bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id = bouts.boxer_2
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON opp_bouts.boxer_1 = opponent.id AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
    WHERE bouts.bout_date < '" . $to_date . "' 
    AND bouts.boxer_1 = '" . $boxer_id . "' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT bouts.boxer_1 AS boxer, bouts.boxer_2 AS opponent, opp_bouts.boxer_1 AS opponentsPrevOpponent
    FROM bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id = bouts.boxer_2
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON opp_bouts.boxer_2 = opponent.id AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
    WHERE bouts.bout_date < '" . $to_date . "' 
    AND bouts.boxer_1 = '" . $boxer_id . "' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT bouts.boxer_2 AS boxer, bouts.boxer_1 AS opponent, opp_bouts.boxer_2 AS opponentsPrevOpponent
    FROM bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id = bouts.boxer_1
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON opp_bouts.boxer_1 = opponent.id AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
    WHERE bouts.bout_date < '" . $to_date . "' 
    AND bouts.boxer_2 = '" . $boxer_id . "' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT bouts.boxer_2 AS boxer, bouts.boxer_1 AS opponent, opp_bouts.boxer_1 AS opponentsPrevOpponent
    FROM bouts
    LEFT JOIN boxers opponent ON opponent.id = bouts.boxer_1
    LEFT JOIN bouts opp_bouts ON opp_bouts.boxer_2 = opponent.id AND opp_bouts.bout_date < bouts.bout_date
    WHERE bouts.bout_date < '" . $to_date . "' 
    AND bouts.boxer_2 = '" . $boxer_id . "' 
) Sub1
```

This way you can get the values you need in the subselects rather than using IF statements on the various aggregate functions

Comment: OP will be better off with a `union all` imho, to avoid the (needless) uniq operator...

Comment: I'm struggling to get my head around this, and can't get it to work to see what it is returning. I fixed the 'Every derived table must have its own alias' error by putting `AS my_table` at the end, but now it's giving me a `Duplicate column name 'bout_id'` error? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to specify the columns you want from each joined table in the queries. bout_id is repeated in both copies of the bouts table so you need to know which one you want to use. The code above was intended as a brief idea to base your query on (ie, it gets the details of a boxers previous bouts) rather than a full solution as I cannot work out what fields you want and how you need to derive them.

Comment: I've been trying for a good hour and i can't seem to get my head round how it's working. I'll give it another few then i may be back. Ah the joys of programming... thanks so far

Comment: Really struggling with this. I thought sleep would help... it didn't. I still don't understand how/where i calculate which boxer is the opponent. Should i be doing this in `SELECT SomeFields, IF(,,)` or am i missing the whole point in your query? If i specify the results i need in the unioned queries, they seem to get cancels/overridden by another query in the union and give me incorrect values. I hope i'm making sense?

Comment: The whole point of the query was to try and give you a standard format row (for which you will need to change the * to the appropriate fields from the tables) so you know that the first column is the boxer and the 2nd is their opponent, etc, so that rather than needing to use an IF to decide which column you are interested in they are already in place. I will edit it to try and make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @john - now edited. You will need to add more columns for the details you want to sum in the sub selects but I hope this gives you the idea. Note that the tables the columns come from vary in each UNIONed select, depending on which boxer is set up as boxer_1 or boxer_2 on the bouts tables.

Comment: @Kickstart You have no idea how much this has helped the application, and i hope you realise how happy you have made me (after a prolonged struggle on my own). At worst it's a load quicker, but I've added the final query to my post as I'm not 100% it's exactly as you had in mind?

Comment: @john - no problem. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

For add speed to your SQL query you may use temporary table to do your left join and after to all your select sum and if

create temporary table new_temp_table
as
select *
from Your query

and after :

select (all your select code)
from new_temp_table

When you use temporary table this can be helpfull in your case, not do your query in one time but in 2 or more time this can improve the time execution. 2-3 query more simple is faster thant 1 quesry 3 time complexe.  After the connection SQL close the temporary table is drop

Example (in french): [table temporaire SQL](http://www.phpascal.com/optimisation/SQL/cree-table-temporaire.html)